# jQuery input value focus and blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur, placeholder

I have the following code so that when a users selects an input box the value will disappear, but the default value will then be re-inserted once a user clicks off it.

```
        $(function() {
            var defaultText = '';
            $('input[id=input]').focus(function() {
                defaultText = $(this).val();
                $(this).val('');
            });
            $('input[id=input]').blur(function() {
                $(this).val(defaultText); 
             });
         });
```

However, that's not exactly how I want it. If a user inserts text I don't want the default text to then override what the user has put. I'm also fairly new to jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to put a placeholder?

Comment: You have an issue with both setting and unsetting your `defaultText`... on `focus` it is changing the `defaultText` value to whatever the current value of the input is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `focus()` method you should check to see if it equals the `defaultText` before clearing it, and in your `blur()` function, you just need to check if the `val()` is empty before setting the `defaultText`. If you are going to be working with multiple inputs, it's better to use a class rather than ID, so your selector would be `input.input` when the class is "input". Even if it was an ID, you would reference it as `input#input`.

```
// run when DOM is ready()
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.input').on('focus', function() {
        // On first focus, check to see if we have the default text saved
        // If not, save current value to data()
        if (!$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).val());

        // check to see if the input currently equals the default before clearing it
        if ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).val('');
    });
    $('input.input').on('blur', function() {
        // on blur, if there is no value, set the defaultText
        if ($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText')); 
    });
});
```

Set it in action in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhDwW/).

Comment: I can't set the defaultText within the function, simply because it's going to be used in a lot of places and I don't want to make the js file huge. Is there any work around, because atm if a user types something, then clicks on the input again it gets changed to ''.

Comment: @Karl this doesn't set the `defaultText` in the function. Do you want the default to be whatever the input has when the form was loaded?

Comment: var defaultText = 'Your default text.'; It does. There are different inputs, each with a different defaultText. I need it to not clear the input if a user has inserted something and clicked off, then clicked back on it.

Comment: @Karl I just updated the code to take the initial value and save it to the DOM object using `data()` - from that point on it refers to this value as the "default" and sets it `onBlur` when the input is blank, and `onFocus` clears it if it is equal.

Comment: as another tip, if you **don't** want it to be set to the initial value, you can set it by adding a property of `data-defaultValue="your text"` to the input.

Answer (score 1):

In your blur handler just check if the user has not write anything, in that case put back the default text, like this:

```
         $('input[id=input]').blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val(defaultText); 
            }
         });
```

Comment: Should be $(this).val() == but thanks, I feel a bit stupid for not thinking of that :P

Comment: Yes, I noted that right after posting and edited my answer afterwards to fix it. Hope this has been useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

An old question + I dislike it when people offer another solution instead of fixing my problem but nonetheless: Using a HTML placeholder attribute with a jQuery plugin would solve the issue.

You could also use the HTML data- attributes and write/read from that.